# Can loneliness make you more creative?

Tags: society, life

Can loneliness, living in solitude, or living alone make a person more creative?

Comment: This question may lead to primarily opinion based answers or be too broad. If you have a quote from someone who takes a view on this and ask a question about that quote it may provide more context. Welcome!

Comment: Loneliness is a *feeling* which may or may not be associated with solitude.

Comment: Or perhaps the converse.

Answer (score 1):

People are different in their character and most often it varies when they become old. Some are more creative when they are alone.  You might have read about shipwrecked men who lived alone and made many things for their survival in lonely islands.  But at the same time we should not forget the people who are living alone in lonely houses or in caves like sanyasins who relinquished everything.  Are they creative?

So, **we cannot say that loneliness can always make us more creative**.  Sometimes, after acquiring ideas from the society some people will need loneliness for bringing out their creativity. Most often they hate other disturbances.  But don't forget that they were not in loneliness before their solitude.